# HashiCorp Vault policy for create/delete namespace

Tags: hashicorp-vault

In the `/org/teams/my-team` I have configured an AppRole. I'd like to grant my AppRole permission to create and delete namespaces underneath my `my-team` namespace.

**How will the policy look like for this case?**

I can achieve the desired with

```
path "*" {
    capabilities = ["create", "delete"]
}
```

but of course, this is too powerful.

I could not find anything helpful in the official HashiCorp [docs.](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/concepts/policies)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general policy path for namespaces is at `sys/namespaces`. You can confirm this with the API endpoints for namespaces. Your policy would appear like:

```
path "sys/namespaces" {
  capabilities = ["list"]
}

path "sys/namespaces/my-team" {
  capabilities = ["list", "read"]
}

path "sys/namespaces/my-team/*" {
  capabilities = ["create", "read", "update", "delete", "list", "sudo"]
}
```